# UIWebView - How to Disable Action Sheets (UIActionSheet)?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, uiwebview

I would like to know how you can disable UIActionSheets, specifically the Action Sheets being displayed after tapping and holding hyperlinks in a UIWebView. These seem to be enabled by default in UIWebViews containing the link address of the respective link in the title of the alert. They are also enabled in Safari.

(How) is it possible to disable all Action Sheets of this kind within a UIWebView?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7):

I just found this solution myself.  Add this to your CSS:

```
body {
  -webkit-touch-callout: none;
}
```

To be clear, this disables the *action sheet* that appears when you hold down a hyperlink.

Comment: Yea, you are right, I wrote the wrong one, but meant the Action Sheet, not an Alert. Thank you very much! ;-)

Answer (score 3):

You can also handle this via JavaScript by calling:

```
document.documentElement.style.webkitTouchCallout = "none";
```

Answer (score 2):

```
 - (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView
 {
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.style.webkitTouchCallout='none'; document.body.style.KhtmlUserSelect='none'"];
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

The dataDetectorTypes property might be what you are looking for. 
If you want to disable that action sheet possibility, just insert the code:

```
webView.dataDetectorTypes = UIDataDetectorTypeNone;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can override presentViewController in UINavigationController and do nothing like this.

```
@implementation CDVInAppBrowserNavigationController : UINavigationController

- (void)presentViewController:(UIViewController *)viewControllerToPresent animated: (BOOL)flag completion:(void (^ __nullable)(void))completion NS_AVAILABLE_IOS(5_0){
    //Do nothing.
}

@end
```