# changing the options displayed in uiwebview for link

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiwebview

Is that possible to display options in uiwebview links. When you touch and hold a 3 options come up, (open, copy and cancel). Is there a way to add a option say "open in safari browser", so that the user can open it either in safari or in the app's embedded browser ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use the webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType: callback of webview delegate to add your custom behaviour.

Comment: is there way to overide that actionsheet displayed ?

Comment: Hum... when is the actionsheet displayed ?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2808267/uiwebview-how-to-disable-action-sheets-uiactionsheet/2851674#2851674. i got it !